# How to copy and paste the data from one excel workbook to another existing workbook using .NET code

Tags: .net

Please help, I am creating an appilication in .NEt where I have to copy one excelbook data to another **existing** excel book.

How to copy and paste the data from one excel workbook to another existing workbook using .NET code.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this:

1. [Microsoft Excel Object Library](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/302096)
2. [MDAC and Oledb](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/Excel_data_access.aspx)
3. [VSTO](http://weblogs.asp.net/SBehera/archive/2006/04/24/443847.aspx)

Comment: Hi Stefan,I want to use VSTO, and the provided link I have already seen. Can you provide me any example with source code.

Comment: @saurav2109: Have you tried any of the examples provided via the link? The examples on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1ad4d8d6.aspx (linked via the VSTO link) seems pretty straight forward.

Comment: they are straight forward and rite now I don't have time to write the code for you sorry...